# How to find the smallest contiguous subarray with maximum sum?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

Kadane's algorithm can find us the maximum contiguous subarray sum and the starting and ending index but the contiguous subarray is not necessarily smallest always. For example : 10 5 -12 7 -10 20 30 -10 50 60. Cumulative sum of the whole array is 150. Cumulative sum of the last 5 elements is also 150. How would you modify the algorithm to find the smallest subarray?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this in `O(n)` with two traversals. In the first traversal, use Kadane's algorithm to find the maximum sum, `S`. For the second traversal, there is a good description at https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-subarray-with-sum-at-least-k/solution/ of maintaining a two-ended queue of indexes to the array's prefix sums so as to be able to keep the indexes of a monotonically increasing list of `prefix_left` that we can compare with `prefix_right` (the current index) subtracted by `S`. We are looking for the smallest `r - l` such that `prefixes[l] ≤ prefixes[r] - S`. While `prefixes[l] ≥ prefixes[r]`, pop left. Then while `prefixes[l] ≤ prefixes[r] - S` update the solution and pop left (since any greater `r` index would only generate a larger interval against the same `l`). Append `y` to the queue.